# Insert eloquent objects/output into collection

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent

I want to put all the eloquent output rows into a collection. At the moment I get only one rwo back. What I have to change?

```
$spieltagSpiel = Spielplan::where('Spieltag', '=', 1)->get();
    foreach($spieltagSpiel as $spieltagSpielOutput){
        $collection = collect([
            ['Spielplan_ID'=>$spieltagSpielOutput->Spielplan_ID]
        ]);
    }
```

This is my output in the view

```
@foreach($names as $outputNames)
    <li>{{$outputNames['Spielplan_ID']}}</li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

why you dont use from array?

```
$arr = [];

$spieltagSpiel = Spielplan::where('Spieltag', '=', 1)->get();
    foreach($spieltagSpiel as $spieltagSpielOutput){

 $arr[] = [
            'Spielplan_ID'=>$spieltagSpielOutput->Spielplan_ID
          ];
    }
```

in view you can foreach on $arr like this :

```
@foreach($arr as $key => $outputNames)
    <li>{{$outputNames['Spielplan_ID']}}</li>
@endforeach
```